# Stock Chart - Formatted Tooltip And Prefixes or Suffixes Not Showing

Tags: highcharts

I am using a stock chart to show trend data. On the backend I am getting what the valueSuffix should be (or valuePrefix as the case may be). I am also formatting the date display in the tooltip. Here is the important part of the series declaration:

```
...
           name: 'Wages',
            tooltip: {
                valuePrefix: '$',
                valueDecimals: 0
            },
...
```

Here is the tooltip formatter:

```
...
    tooltip: {
        formatter: function () {
            var s = '<b>';
            if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.x) == 'Jan') {
                s = s + 'Q1';
            }
            if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.x) == 'Apr') {
                s = s + 'Q2';
            }
            if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.x) == 'Jul') {
                s = s + 'Q3';
            }
            if (Highcharts.dateFormat('%b', this.x) == 'Oct') {
                s = s + 'Q4';
            }
            s = s + ' ' + Highcharts.dateFormat('%Y', this.x) + '</b>';
            $.each(this.points, function (i, point) {
                s += '<br/><span style="color: ' + point.series.color + '">' + point.series.name + ':</span>' + point.y;
            });
            return s;
        }
    }
...
```

[Example jsFiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/JT8MG/)

If you notice the prefix for the dollar sign is not showing on the Wage series. I am not really sure what I am missing here.

Comment: I think `tooltip` is not available for `series`.

Answer (score 6):

The fix is to break up the label formatting and the value formatting into distinct sections. See example [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wergeld/JT8MG/3/).

Set the chart.tooltip like:

```
...
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<b>{point.key}</b><br>',
            xDateFormat: '%Q'
        },
...
```

On the xAxis I replaced the label formatter with:

```
...
format: '{value: %Q}'
...
```

Inside the series I kept my suffix/prefix/decimals the same:

```
...
            tooltip: {
                valuePrefix: '$',
                valueDecimals: 0
            },
...
```

The big change came when I found that you can set your own date format label. I created one for Quarters (which is what I did the original cumbersome code for):

```
Highcharts.dateFormats = {
    Q: function (timestamp) {
        var date = new Date(timestamp);
        var y = date.getFullYear();
        var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
        if (m <= 3) str = "Q1 " + y;
        else if (m <= 6) str = "Q2 " + y;
        else if (m <= 9) str = "Q3 " + y;
        else str = "Q4 " + y;
        return str;
    }
};
```

I now get the tooltip to show the correct labels.

Comment: The problem was simple - tooltip.formatter has higher priority than tooltip.valueSuffix/Prefix. If you are using tooltip formatter, you can set there directly suffix/prefix.

Comment: @PawełFus, correct - but, since I am building the chart options at runtime and the series will not all have the same prefix or suffix (or decimal) setting these options in the tooltip.formatter would make them global. The workaround for that would be to do a series of case statements (or if/then) inside the formatter based on the series title - that is not really desirable as we currently have 70+ series spread across 30 pages. This solution, to me anyway, is much simpler and also "cleaner" in the code - setting tooltip options that apply to each series in their respective series options.

Comment: that is a nice solution

Answer (score 0):

Unless something has changed in a recent version, you can't set your tooltip options within the series object.  You can set anything that you would set in the plotOptions on the series level, but not the tooltip.

You can set a check within your main tooltip formatter to check for the series name, and apply the prefix accordingly.

{{edit::

This appears to be an issue of the formatter negating the valuePrefix setting.

Comment: According to the documentation it appears you can do this: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.series.tooltip.

Comment: Checking for series name and adding the appropriate prefix or suffix is not an option as there could be any number of series titles and that is a terrible list to have to maintain let alone load for every single chart even if it is only using 1 series title out of 100.

Comment: I was unaware of this addition.  good to know. updated answer.  no solution off hand, however.

Comment: I might have a "fix". Taking some refactoring of our code. But, in the end it will be cleaner to read as well.

Answer (score 0):

Old question... but I spent hours looking for an acceptable way to do this.

#### /!\ : Before OP's answer...

If someone is looking for a way to use the formatter provided by highcharts (`pointFormat` attribute) (Doc here: [LABELS AND STRING FORMATTING](http://www.highcharts.com/docs/chart-concepts/labels-and-string-formatting)), you will find a (bad) example here :

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/tooltip/pointformat/

Why "bad" ? because if you change :

```
pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y}</b><br/>',
```

with :

```
pointFormat: '{series.name}: <b>{point.y:,.1f}</b><br/>',
```

you add thousand separators (useless here) and force number format to 1 decimal ... and loose the suffix.

**The answer is** : `series.options.tooltip.valueSuffix` (or `series.options.tooltip.valuePrefix`)

Example :

```
pointFormat: '<span style="color:{series.color}">\u25CF</span> {series.name}: <b>{point.y:,.0f}{series.options.tooltip.valueSuffix}</b><br/>',
```

Hope this will save you some time.

---

### Now OP's Answer :

Based on what I said, you can change :

```
$.each(this.points, function (i, point) {
   s += '<br/><span style="color: ' + point.series.color + '">' + point.series.name + ':</span>' + point.y;
});
```

For this :

```
$.each(this.points, function (i, point) {
    s += '<br/><span style="color: ' + point.series.color + '">' 
      + point.series.name + ':</span>'
      + (typeof point.series.options.tooltip.valuePrefix !== "undefined" ?
            point.series.options.tooltip.valuePrefix : '')
      + point.y
      + (typeof point.series.options.tooltip.valueSuffix !== "undefined" ?
            point.series.options.tooltip.valueSuffix : '');
});
```

This will add prefix and/or suffix if they exists